# Weird issue on properties with John Resig simple inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'm referring to [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/).
I'm basically creating a class with an `init` function which set an `options` attribute. see http://jsbin.com/usaboh/1/edit for the working example (enable the console to see the output).

Below the first example works fine, however the second still get the `options` value of the first "instance".

Works as expected :

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    options: {value: 2},
    init: function(options){
        if(options) {
            this.options = options;
        }
    }
});

var p = new Person({value: 5});
console.log(p.options); //{"value": 5} (ok)

var p2 = new Person();
console.log(p2.options); //{"value": 2} (ok)
```

Doesn't work as expected :

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    options: {value: 2},
    init: function(options){
        if(options) {
            for (var name in options) {
                this.options[name] = options[name];
            }
        }
    }
});

var p = new Person({value: 5});
console.log(p.options); //{"value": 5} (ok)

var p2 = new Person();
console.log(p2.options); //{"value": 5} (why 5 ??? shouldn't be 2 ?)
```

Why the value of `options` in the second instance is not `{"value": 2}` like in the first example ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `options` is a property of the class (on its prototype), not the object.

Verify it by adding this to the bottom of your second example:

```
console.log( p.options == p2.options ); // true
```

---

## Explanation:

When using abstraction layers, it is very important to remember the underlying principles, so that you don't get bitten by the [abstractions' leaks](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

### Your 1st example:

Let's re-write your class definition with regular Prototypal inheritance:

```
var Person = function (options) {
    if (options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
};

Person.prototype.options = {value: 2};

var john = new Person();
```

`john` will now be a new instance of `Person` and will *not* have an `options` property:

```
john.hasOwnProperty('options'); // false
```

When trying to access the `options` via `john.options`, you'll get the `{value: 2}` from the prototype chain.

If however you were to create this new `Person` object by supplying your `options` to the constructor:

```
var michael = new Person({value:5});
```

`michael` *will* have an `options` property:

```
michael.hasOwnProperty('options'); // true
```

Here's a simple test comparing the two:

```
john.options == Person.prototype.options // true
michael.options == Person.prototype.options // false
```

---

### Your 2nd example:

Now consider your second example, written in native Prototypal inheritance:

```
var Person = function (options) {
    if (options) {
        for (var name in options) {
            this.options[name] = options[name];
        }
    }
};

Person.prototype.options = {value: 2};
```

Regardless of whether you pass `options` into the constructor, your new object will never have its own `options` property. All you're doing is augmenting the `options` on the prototype:

```
var john = new Person();
john.options // {value:2}
john.hasOwnProperty('options'); // false
john.options == Person.prototype.options // true

var michael = new Person({value:5});
michael.options // {value:5}
michael.hasOwnProperty('options'); // false
michael.options == Person.prototype.options // true

john.options // {value:5}
// Why? Because they share the same `options` property from the prototype
john.options == michael.options // true
```

If you then go and assign a new object to `john`, it won't affect the `options` on the prototype:

```
john.options = {value:10};
john.options // {value:10}
john.options == Person.prototype.options // false
michael.options // {value:5}
michael.options == john.options // false
michael.options == Person.prototype.options // true
```

---

## Solution:

To get the functionality you want in your second example, you'll have to follow these steps:

1. Create a new `options` property from within the constructor (the `init` method).
2. Copy all the properties from `Person.prototype.options`.
3. Finally, copy all the properties from the `options` argument.

Here's how you might do that:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    options: {value: 2},
    init: function(options) {
        if (options) {
            var name, prototypeOptions = Person.prototype.options;
            this.options = {};

            for (name in prototypeOptions) {
                this.options[name] = prototypeOptions[name];
            }

            for (name in options) {
                this.options[name] = options[name];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If you're using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#extend), you can use their `extend` method, which makes all this trivial:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    options: {value: 2},
    init: function(options) {
        if (options) {
            this.options = $.extend({}, Person.prototype.options, options);
        }
    }
});
```

---

### Simpler solution:

Depending on your needs, you might not even need the `options` to be on the prototype in the first place. Just add it to your object in the constructor (the `init` method), and be done with it:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    init: function(options) {
        this.options = {value: 2};
        if (options) {
            for (var name in options) {
                this.options[name] = options[name];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and once again, if you're using jQuery or underscore, this becomes even simpler:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    init: function(options) {
        this.options = _.extend({value: 2}, options);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you set :
`p.options = {"value": 10};`
, for example, just before the second `new`, the result is the same (i.e. `{"value": 5}`). So i don't think it's a kind of collision issue.

Comment: @Jails - when using an abstraction, you have to remember the principals of the underlying layer. I thought it was pretty obvious, but seemingly I'm wrong. I added a [lengthy] explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks to untangled all of this, really appreciate the effort !

Comment: @Jails You use the terms "native" and "regular" prototypal inheritance. I have never heard those used before, and I would normally assume they were the same. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @oligofren - I guess that last question was supposed to be directed to me. There's no difference between the two; I'm using them interchangeably. All I meant was writing the prototypal inheritance ourselves, rather than relying on John's abstraction.